# MySQL Store Procedure - Setting AUTO_INCREMENT value

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench, auto-increment

I am in trouble coding a store procedure as shown below

```
CREATE DEFINER=`dbcomexuser`@`%` PROCEDURE `clearance_imp`(IN CAPIfilename VARCHAR(12))
BEGIN

DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;
DECLARE _refID INT DEFAULT 0;

START TRANSACTION;

SELECT MAX(imp_id) + 1 INTO _refID FROM temp_imp;

INSERT INTO filenamedt (filename, filedate) VALUES (CAPIfilename, now());

INSERT INTO imp__description (imp_id, imp_description) (SELECT imp_id, TRIM(descricaoProduto) FROM temp_imp);

TRUNCATE TABLE temp_imp;

ALTER TABLE temp_imp AUTO_INCREMENT = _refID;

IF `_rollback` THEN
    ROLLBACK;
ELSE
    COMMIT;
END IF;
END
```

The main issue is that MySQL Workbench outputs that there is an error at line:

```
ALTER TABLE temp_imp AUTO_INCREMENT = _refID;
```

But I can't figure out what is going on.

Does someone can help me?

Comment: Do you know what the value of `_refID`? Also, I'm not `mysql`, but I would think that `SELECT MAX(imp_id) + 1 INTO _refID FROM temp_imp_;` might cause an error because of the table name with the extra underscore at the end?

Comment: @SS_DBA it was a typing mistake when I transcript the code

Comment: I doubt that the parameter variable name `_refID` will be substituted with variable value.

Comment: @Akina it is exactly what I am trying to do. At this line `SELECT MAX(imp_id) + 1 INTO _refID FROM temp_imp;` I set _refID to use at this line `ALTER TABLE temp_imp AUTO_INCREMENT = _refID;`. But I don't know why, it is not working

Comment: Table option parameter is treated as LITERAL, not as substitutable parameter. Moreover, as a literal of wrong datatype. It is not number because contains non-digits, it is not string or date because it is not quoted, it is not some pre-defined constant... So it is a typo.

Comment: @Akina, any suggestions to fix it? I do not have so much experience in MySQL

Comment: No fix it seems. The task needs in dynamic SQL - but ALTER TABLE is not allowed in PREPARE.

Comment: Do you have any idea what should I do in order to restore auto_increment number?